# How to retrieve INT value from TEXT box using Selenium/Webdriver Python binding?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, python

I have this code:

```
tcost = driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_txtTotalCost").text
total = int(tcost)
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_txtVisa").send_keys(total/2)
driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_txtCash").send_keys(total/2)
```

It throws this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I need to convert `text` in text box to `int` to do some calculations over it and sure, If you have any suggestions to enhance the code please do.

Comment: The int function should convert a valid string to an integer.  Why do you think it fails?  Have you tried printing/logging the string?

Comment: What language - Java ?

Comment: @phil python language

Comment: @user246 i tried print(tcost),it should print the value of the text box in the IDLE i'm using right?!,as it gave new empty line only and then >>> for next actions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to use `.get_attribute("value")`. instead of `.text`.

Comment: it gives that error 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: .get_attribute("value") worked thaaaaaaaaaaanx